# The app delegate must implement the window property if it wants to use a main storyboard file. (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I get this error only when trying to run on the actual iPhone:

> The app delegate must implement the window property if it wants to use a main storyboard file.

When I run in the iOS simulator, it works fine.

I've searched all similar problems and solutions provided here on stackoverflow, but none of them worked for me.

Based on suggestions here on Stack Overflow I've tried the following in the AppDelegate.swift to no avail:

```
var window: UIWindow?
var storyBoard: UIStoryboard?
var initialViewController: UIViewController?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    print("entered")
    storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    initialViewController = storyBoard?.instantiateInitialViewController()
    window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

What could the issue be?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? What version of iOS is on the iPhone? What version of iOS were you using in the simulator?

Comment: Xcode 11, iOS 12.1 on the iPhone, in the simulator it works fine both in iOS 12.1 and iOS 13